# Forecasting the spikes in time series river gage data

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, hydrology

I have an idea for a personal project knitting together river level gage data with weather data sets to look at how upstream and surrounding area rainfall events affect river levels. I would probably also use this for my capstone project in my MS Analytics program. Ultimately I would like to make a tool that looks at weather predictions in a watershed and predicts what a specific river gage will be at over the next 7 days, as this would be of tremendous value to the kayaking community. The important thing is the spikes though, a river may only be high enough to kayak for a few hours before the level drops again. Most forecasting algorithms I've looked at seem more focused on tempering spikes than predicting them.

I feel like rivers and junctions are inherently a network graph and that could be a good way to organize this, but complicated. Initially I want to just try and make it work without modeling the river network or collecting/using complicated meteorological/geographical/hydrological variables. I have 10-20 years of river data for each site and matching weather history.

I think calibrating the model separately for each month will minimize seasonality issues and I am sure I need to focus on predicting the change in gage height rather than the actual gage height. Some of the things that are tripping me up include whether I need to move away from time series data and how to deal with the variable time delay between a rain event 100 miles away and the gage height change that occurs from it.

Basically, I think my approach is to build a micro model through simple regression at each site that says "given no rain in the watershed in 24 hours, in january, that gauge will drop by 2% per hour." or "given 1 inch of rain in 24 hours in the direct vicinity, that gauge will rise by 30% per hour." Then it seems to be not too tricky to combine these predictions with the current gage level and current rainfall estimates and arrive back at a chart of the next few days.

Here is an example of the gage data I'm using:
https://waterdata.usgs.gov/usa/nwis/uv?03518500

Any thoughts or guidance?

Comment: Could you include some description of the data? How many gauge points, how many  weather stations? What is the time resolution? Maybe start with some plots, some simple models, autocorrelation and crosscorrelation functions ...

Comment: This is probably too unfocused for our site.  I will mention, though, that I have undertaken to construct such a model and, as expected, discovered it did not work well.  In my case the failures were due to storage of precipitation that occurred during the winter months.  It is possible that in very limited climates--the high deserts surrounding the Grand Canyon of the Colorado come to mind--you might succeed without constructing a detailed hydrological model of the entire water system. (I should add that I watched East Coast US rivers closely for decades and know a simple model will fail.)

Comment: The smoothness of the curve in the USGS data graph suggests a predictive fit as opposed to actual water flow. That said, *spikiness* (sp?) or *burstiness* in data can be modeled in many ways, beginning with fast fourier transforms to capture periodicity. Other options include the methods developed for modeling neuronal patterns in burstiness as they fire, e.g., Karsai, Jo and Kaski, Bursty Human Dynamics, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.02580.pdf

Comment: In addition, Eager et al., Beyond velocity and acceleration: jerk, snap and higher derivatives, 2016, Eur. J. Phys. 37, https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0143-0807/37/6/065008/pdf  suggest modeling physical parameters beyond the first derivative (slope or velocity) and second derivative (acceleration or the rate of change in velocity) to third derivatives (jerk or the rate of change in acceleration) and fourth derivatives (snap or the rate of change in jerk).

Comment: Discharge curves for moderate or large watersheds (catchments, basins) are genuinely smooth because of a mix of what is on going upstream [literally!] on different space and time scales, which has a smoothing tendency.  Discharge is almost always much more complicated than past rainfall shunted downstream. Hence, this is a much more difficult project than may at first appear, as  @whuber hints also.

Comment: @Mike None of those approaches are effective for this problem. A river system is a complex network driven by precipitation, storage, vegetative cover, etc., combining in complex ways from upstream contributions to produce the observed gauge (or flow) readings at downstream monitoring points.  The responses are decidedly not periodic, because they are driven by relatively rare occasional events: paddlers know, intimately, that just a few days contribute most of a small river's total annual discharge. The only periodicity I have ever seen was due to diurnal control of large dams.

Comment: “It seems that the rivers know the theory. It only remains to convince the engineers of the validity of the analysis.” E.J. Gumbel. Yes, a simple regression won't work but the OP wants some guidance on a master's level course, not a sophisticated statistical analysis of the ecology of river systems intended for peer-reviewed publication. All of this suggests reverting to a 2-stage, Tobit-type model where, in the first stage, the likelihood of an "extreme, occasional or rare" event is estimated and, in the second stage, a prediction is made of the expected discharge, given that event.